# refactor too many if...else statements while reading map structure in java

Tags: java, refactoring

there is a logic need to read some value and assign different variable, is there any good way to improve the codes that makes the structure more graceful and code lines short?  the codes as below:
The structure of rows is `List<Map<String, Object>>`

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(rows)) {
  for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    Long regionId = -1L; Long principalId = -1L; Long categoryId = -1L;
    String mainCategoryName = ""; String subCategoryName = ""; String level3CategoryName = "";
    Long lft = -1L; Long rft = -1L; Long parentId = -1L;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> cell : row.entrySet()) {
      if (cell.getKey().equals("country")) {
        regionId = Region.getRegionByName(cell.getValue().toString().toLowerCase()).getDbVal();
      } else if (cell.getKey().equals("main_cat")) {
        categoryId = Long.parseLong(cell.getValue().toString());
      } else if (cell.getKey().equals("sub_cat")) {
        lft = Long.parseLong(cell.getValue().toString());
      } else if (cell.getKey().equals("level3_cat")) {
        rft = Long.parseLong(cell.getValue().toString());
      } else if (cell.getKey().equals("main_category")) {
        mainCategoryName = cell.getValue().toString();
      } else if (cell.getKey().equals("sub_category")) {
        subCategoryName = cell.getValue().toString();
      } else if (cell.getKey().equals("level3_category")) {
        level3CategoryName = cell.getValue().toString();
      }
    }
    List<CategoryDto> categoryDtoList = getList(regionId, categoryId, lft, rft, mainCategoryName, subCategoryName, level3CategoryName);

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a switch-case-case is much easier to read. but his is not really a question for SO, rather a code-review site

Comment: yep, I agree that switch-case-case is easier to read, however, code line can't be reduced and not solved fundamentally

Comment: @ZhangXin To solve it "fundamentally", this piece shouldn't have done this much. It's hard to generalise something when your input is an `Object`, and your output could be a `Long`, a `String`, or an instance of a custom class (I assume that's what `Region` is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a map, why not directly get the value by providing the key name, rather than iterating and checking the key names.

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(rows)) {
        for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
            Long regionId = row.containsKey("country") ?
                    Region.getRegionByName(row.get("country").toString().toLowerCase()).getDbVal() : -1L;
            Long principalId = row.containsKey("main_cat") ? Long.parseLong(row.get("main_cat").toString()) : -1L;
            Long categoryId = -1L;
            String mainCategoryName = row.containsKey("main_category") ? row.get("main_category").toString() : "";
            String subCategoryName = row.containsKey("sub_category") ? row.get("sub_category").toString() : "";
            String level3CategoryName = row.containsKey("level3_category") ? row.get("level3_category").toString() : "";;
            Long lft = row.containsKey("sub_cat") ? Long.parseLong(row.get("sub_cat").toString()) : -1L;
            Long rft = row.containsKey("level3_cat") ? Long.parseLong(row.get("level3_cat").toString()) : -1L;
            Long parentId = -1L;

            List<CategoryDto> categoryDtoList = getList(regionId, categoryId, lft, rft, mainCategoryName, subCategoryName, level3CategoryName);

        }
    }
```

Or if you are using Java 8 or later, you can add a small utility method as below, and the above code can be further reduced.

```
private <T> T calculateIfKeyPresent(Map<String, Object> row, String key, Function<Object, T> calculator,
                                   T defaultValue) {
    return row.containsKey(key) ? calculator.apply(row.get(key)) : defaultValue;
}
```

Reduced code,

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    Long regionId = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "country",
            (value) -> Region.getRegionByName(value.toString().toLowerCase()).getDbVal(), -1L);
    Long principalId = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "main_cat", (value) -> Long.parseLong(value.toString()), -1L);
    Long categoryId = -1L;
    String mainCategoryName = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "main_category", Object::toString, "");
    String subCategoryName = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "sub_category", Object::toString, "");
    String level3CategoryName = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "level3_category", Object::toString, "");
    Long lft = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "sub_cat", (value) -> Long.parseLong(value.toString()), -1L);
    Long rft = calculateIfKeyPresent(row, "level3_cat", (value) -> Long.parseLong(value.toString()), -1L);
    Long parentId = -1L;

    List<CategoryDto> categoryDtoList = getList(regionId, categoryId, lft, rft, mainCategoryName, subCategoryName, level3CategoryName);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be ideal, but you can use [Map#getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

```
        categoryId = Long.parseLong(row.getOrDefault("main_cat", "-1").toString());
        lft = Long.parseLong(row.getOrDefault("sub_cat", "-1").toString());
        rft = Long.parseLong(row.getOrDefault("sub_cat", "-1").toString());
        mainCategoryName = row.getOrDefault("main_category", "").toString(); 
        subCategoryName = row.getOrDefault("main_category", "").toString();
        level3CategoryName = row.getOrDefault("level3_category", "").toString();
```

It basically does what you are trying to do: use value if it exists in the map, or use default value otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to modify various variables, depending on the input. Because of the way Java handles lambdas (as closures), you cannot do this in a generic way without creating a wrapper. For this, create a class such as:

```
public class DataContainer {

    private String regionId;
    private String mainCategoryName;
    // any more fields needed

    // getters and setters here
}
```

You then need a way to associate **inputs** to **actions**. A `Map` is ideal for this. Your inputs are `String`s, and your actions can be represented by `Consumer<DataContainer>` (since they are actions which take a `DataContainer` and run some code on it).

You can then create a `Map<String, Consumer<DataContainer>>`, and put mappings into it, as follows:

```
Map<String, Consumer<DataContainer>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("country", container -> container.setCountry("some input"));  // when the input is "country", container.setCountry("some input") gets called

// add as needed
```

In your code, to execute the instructions from the map, you would do the following;

```
DataContainer container = ...  // initialized somewhere else

String input = cell.getKey();

map.getOrDefault(input,  // find the function associated with the input
    container -> {}  // if it can't find an input, simply do nothing ( {} represents an empty block of code) 
).accept(container);  // finally, pass the container to that function, and have it executed
```

Although you still need a long list of `map.put(key, consumer);` calls when you initialise your `Map`, this process has the advantage of being:

- modifiable at runtime
- iterable over (for example, if you decide you need to execute ALL code blocks, or those matching a certain predicate)
- not hardcoded - a  could be passed in by another user of your code.